# Using "get" in place of "start"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Can we make up such a sentence which means "start liking something"?

> I get to like this pastry.

And also should it be "get to like" or "get liking"?

Comment: I'd rather say "it's growing on me".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a marked/dialectal way of saying it, but I've heard it before.  I have heard it more like:

> I am getting to like this pastry

As in, getting closer to liking it than you were at the start.

Comment: But is that grammatically correct use?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing ungrammatical about it, but is less common, I believe.

Comment: What about `get liking` form? Is that also correct?

Comment: In my neck of the woods, "I am getting to like" is far closer to standard than "I get to like." I am struggling to recall even a single instance of the latter.

Comment: @Braveyard I could get to liking this pastry is not common either, but that construction would be understandable, though a bit awkward I think.  Other variations without *get* is I'm not liking this pastry.  The positive would be I'm liking this pastry.

Comment: @Spare Oom, I think it is fairly common in the South, if nowhere else.  Also, I think omitting the _get_ changes the meaning to a simple copula statement, whereas leaving it in shifts it to the Imperfect (Progressive?) tense.

Comment: Point taken, @Mark T Since the OP asked about using *get* in place of *start*, I should point out that *start* instead of *get*, would not actually work well with my above example.  I'm not sure one would hear *I could start to liking this pastry.*